# Applying Knockout Bindings is Clearing jQuery Data in IE 7 and 8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, knockout.js, internet-explorer-7

I have an application that's running Knockout with a few jQuery plugins, the one in question here being jQuery UI Tabs.

Through some searching, I've found that the data held by jQuery's data plugin `($(someElt).data())` exists until I apply the bindings through Knockout.

After that, the data held by jQuery is gone, which makes the plugin think it's not initialized.

What makes this stranger is that my outer set of tabs (there are tabs for the page and tabs in one of the panes of the page's tabs) works fine.
The inner tabs, however, have this issue.

There are no bindings directly on either of the containers for the tabs, though there are some on elements inside and outside of both (though neither should cause any actual removal of DOM elements).

Any thoughts?

Edit: Here is a test case I created (I'm using jQuery 1.9.2 and Knockout 2.2.1):

```
<div id="OutterTabContainer">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#OutterTab1">Outter Tab 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#OutterTab2">Outter Tab 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="OutterTab1">
    This is the first tab.
    <div data-bind="visible: test2">This should be invisible</div>

  </div>
  <div id="OutterTab2">
    This is the second tab.
    <div data-bind="text: test1()"></div>

    <div data-bind="with: testObj()">
      <div id="InnerTabContainer">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#InnerTab1">Inner Tab 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#InnerTab2">Inner Tab 2</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div id="InnerTab1">
          This is the first of the inner tabs.
        </div>
        <div id="InnerTab2">
          This is the second of the inner tabs.
          @*<div data-bind="text: innerTest()"></div>*@
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  (function($, ko, undefined) {
    var outterTabs = $("#OutterTabContainer"),
        innerTabs = $("#InnerTabContainer"),
        viewModel = {
          test1: ko.observable("test 1"),
          test2: ko.observable(false),
          testObj: ko.observable({
            innerTest: ko.observable("inner")
          })
        };

    //creating tabs, works fine
    outterTabs.tabs();
    innerTabs.tabs();

    setTimeout(function() {
      //simulating an ajax success callback
      ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
      innerTabs.tabs("select", 1);
    }, 1000);

  })(jQuery, ko);
</script>
```

In creating this, I found that the culprit is the "with" binding in tab 2. I'm still not sure why that binding would cause this issue, so I'm still looking for an adequate workaround for this. I guess if push comes to shove, I could defer the inner tab initialization until after the view model is bound.

Edit 2: I've been looking through the knockout source code, and it's looking like the with binding runs the same code as the if and ifnot bindings. It looks like the element bound to the with is turned into a virtual element, and from what I can tell, those virtual elements are destroyed and recreated when bindings are applied, so the element itself (and all child elements, including the tab container) would be a different one from the element that was there before. I'm guessing that's why the data isn't there anymore (since it's saved by dom node).

Comment: Sample code or it didn't happen. Could you please post any **relevant** code as it is hard to replicate or investigate without. In addition please consider putting together a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate the issue. Most of the time when using the bare minimum to put a DEMO together it works fine and one can than extrapolate from there where things go wrong in the real application.

Comment: As you edit hinted, the problem is the `with` binding. When you change a `with` binding (as you do when you first `applyBindings`), knockout will recreate the DOM elements from scratch.

Comment: So, I can either not use the with binding or do my jquery initialization late... Or maybe I can cache the data before binding and reinstate it after?

Comment: @BenjaminMcGregor: One solution would be to add a custom binding to your `#InnerTabContainer` that has only an `.init` function that simply applies the `.tabs()` function. That way, whenever the DOM is recreated, Knockout will tabify your content.

Comment: Ok, so caching and reinstating the data doesn't work since the events for clicking and such were attached to a different dom element. Since the value in this with binding doesn't really change after it's first initialized, I can safely initialize the tabs immediately after the bindings are first applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my suggestion, you could try something like this (now tested!):

```
ko.bindingHandlers["tab"] = {
   init: function(element) {
       $(element).tabs();
   }
};
```

And then:

```
<div id="InnerTabContainer" data-bind="tab: $data">
```

Edit: as it turns out, a binding needs some data, even if you aren't using it.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GeeJ9/1/)

Comment: Thanks. For my immediate needs, that may be a little much (since the value changes), but it is handy to know for future reference. Also, you could probably send it a plain object of the options to use in place of $data to make it more general use.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem with the accordion (from jQuery UI), turns out Benjamin is right about the 'with' handler causing the element to think it is not initialized (thanks man you're a great help).

I tested the solution Matt presented, it is not the $data presented to the element that fixes the problem, it is the initialization of the inner tabs after the binding is done. Which is by the way the only solution I've found so far. 
Is this the only way to fix this?

edit:
After a bit of digging I found out that IE8 does not handle the 'with' handler correctly (virtual elements), removing it will fix the problem.